# How to set a view state in a master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to check whether an event is fired from the master page or not. For that i kept a count in the viewstate . This is throwing exception on page load. I'm just calling the below line in a pageload

```
Int32 count = Int32.Parse(this.ViewState["Count"].ToString());
```

Please help.

Comment: note that viewstate is not shared thrue object. that mean masterpage has it's own, page and each control has it's own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will throw an exception in a few cases.

1. The key "Count" isn't in the view state yet. `ViewState["Count"]` will return null and the `.ToString()` call will throw a `NullReferenceException`.
2. The value of "Count" can't be parsed into an int, throwing a `FormatException`.

Things to try:

- You should check the ordering of your code to make sure that you are setting the value of count before attempting to read from it.

Your code can be improved as follows:

```
Int32 count;
string countStr = this.ViewState["Count"];

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(countStr )
{
    bool ok = Int32.TryParse(countStr, out count);

    if(ok)
    {
        // Do stuff with count
    }
}
```

- You might consider using the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) rather than the ViewState to store custom data between pages.

Comment: It's because ofcase 1 i think. I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Answer (score 0):

```
<pagesenableSessionState="false"enableViewState="false"theme="Default" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `ViewState["Count"]` exist before performing operations to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to default the count value to 0:

```
Int32 count = Int32.Parse((this.ViewState["Count"] ?? "0").ToString());
```

This will stop you seeing an Exception if the "Count" key doesn't exist in the ViewState collection.